# sed + set value inside double quotes

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, perl

The file is like this

```
more /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
# Command-line options for chronyd
OPTIONS=""
```

We need to set the value `-4` inside `""`

The file looks like the following,

```
# Command-line options for chronyd
OPTIONS="-4"
```

We can use sed as

```
sed -i s'/OPTIONS=""/OPTIONS="-4"/g' /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
```

But this not so good option because (if there is a space inside double quotes)

For example,

```
more /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
# Command-line options for chronyd
OPTIONS=" "
```

Comment: There is a typo in your `sed` call: the `s` command should be _inside_ the single quotes (although I'm sure this was not the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` addressing on RE:

```
sed -e '/^OPTIONS=/s/.*/OPTIONS="-4"/' /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
```

Mean:

- On lines matching `^OPTIONS=` (begining by `OPTION=`),

  - do replace *everything* by `OPTIONS="-4"`.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work,

- If `space` is **optional**,

```
sed -r 's/OPTIONS="[[:space:]]?"/OPTIONS="-4"/g'
```

- If `space` is **at least one or more**,

```
sed -r 's/OPTIONS="[[:space:]]+"/OPTIONS="-4"/g'
```

Or both possibilities [As mentioned by @AdminBee],

- If `space` is **at least one or more** or **optional**,

```
sed -r 's/OPTIONS="[[:space:]]*"/OPTIONS="-4"/g'
```

For example,

```
[arif@arif]$ printf '# Command-line options for chronyd\nOPTIONS=" "\n'
# Command-line options for chronyd
OPTIONS=" "
```

```
[arif@arif]$ printf '# Command-line options for chronyd\nOPTIONS=" "\n' | sed -r 's/OPTIONS="[[:space:]]"/OPTIONS="-4"/g'
# Command-line options for chronyd
OPTIONS="-4"
```

Comment: You could also merge both possibilities by stating it as `[[:space:]]*` ...

Comment: sed  -r 's/OPTIONS="[[:space:]]+"/OPTIONS="-4"/g'  /etc/sysconfig/chronyd not works when no space between the double quota

Comment: This is right. As muhammad mentioned, the syntax with `[[:space:]]+` applies if `space` is _at least one or more_. If it is optional, you have to use either `[[:space:]]?` or `[[:space:]]*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
sed  's/^OPTIONS=.*/OPTIONS="-4"/g' /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
```

or

```
sed  's/\(^OPTIONS="\).*"/\1-4"/g' /etc/sysconfig/chronyd
```

Comment: what in case space between new line to OPTIONS ?

Comment: @yael can u plz update the same in question..